# Ember.js how do I pass a component to another component as a parameter?

Tags: ember.js

For example I have two resources - users and groups. And two pages, which handle listings of these resources, which are similar. They both have common logic for pagination and filters, but the resources must be displayed differently, so I wanted to create a `resource-list` component and pass `user-view` and `group-view` components inside as parameters (and resource names for Ember Data). Can I pass a component, or maybe I can do it the other way somehow, because I'm pretty much new to the MVC and that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `{{component}}` helper (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_component).

For example pass the name of the detail view to the resource-list component

```
{{resource-list detailView="user-view"}}
```

or

```
{{resource-list detailView="group-view"}}
```

And in the resource-list component you include the component with the component helper:

```
{{component detailView}}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both component inside resource-list, but you need to show one or other depending of forUserView or forGroupView that you'll pass to your resource-list component.
So inside your resource-list.hbs you can have:

```
{{#if forUserView}}
  {{user-view}}
{{#if}}

{{if forGroupView}}
  {{group-view}}
{{/if}}
```

And when you use resource-list component just define:

```
{{resource-list forUserView=true}}
```

or

```
{{resource-list forGroupView=true}}
```

Comment: Well, that's quite not an elegant solution, but if it's the only alternative. It's just bad for scaling, when I might have more models

Comment: You're right it's not elegant, maybe there's better solution for this, I never had to add more component so I was happy with this solution.

Comment: Check this post I think that it has solution for you
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/26/emberjs-dynamically-render-components/